# Julia- extract part of multidimensional matrix by vector

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia

I am trying to reduce a multidimensional matrix with a vector.

Lets say the matrix A is 1000 x 10 x 100.
The vector b could be 100 x 1 where the 100 entries are part of the first dimension of A.  There is always exactly one element in a slice of the first dimension of A that matches each element of b.

How can i reduce the Matrix to the matching vector?

I tried

```
Ared= A[b,:,:]
```

but it doesn't work.

The new Matrix in this example should have the form 100 x 10 x 100

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There is always exactly one element in the first dimension of A that matches each element of b. I don't entirely understand your second question. In general i want to creat a new matrix that has the same shape as the original, but the first dimension is reduced to vector b.

Comment: your question is ambiguous and has attracted two contradicting but potentially valid answers, depending on what it is you actually want; can you specify exactly what you want? For example, if "A" was `A = reshape(0.1:0.1:2.4, 3,4,2)` and b was a 2 element vector, can you give an example of `b` and intended output? Is `b` a vector of row indices that you want to use to select a subrange of `A`? (e.g. `b = [1;3]`) or are you saying "b can take any two values from the values available in `A(1,:,:)`  (e.g. `b = [0.4; 1.9]`) ? Please clarify.

Comment: If it is the former, then use my answer. If it is the latter, use Michael's answer. If it is neither, please rephrase and clarify your problem with an appropriate example.

Comment: The first answer soved my Problem, but the second was also helpfull in a general manner.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad you sorted it. Please mark the answer you consider correct as accepted, for future viewers. (I'm still not sure which one you mean, hahah)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I see what you're asking.  You're looking for the `findin()` function.  It takes two arguments, each of which is a collection.  It finds the elements of the first collection that are in the second, and returns the indices of those.  Thus, we can apply this function to a slice from the first dimension of your array.  Below are examples, starting in 2D, for simplicity, and then generalizing to 3D, which really is basically the same.

Note that it is necessary to select specific indices along the second and third dimensions (here I chose 1 for each), since otherwise, there is no definite element in the first dimension slice to compare to the contents of `b`. (each dimension simply supplying one part of, in this case, a set of 3 numbers which *together* identify a specific place within the 3D array).

```
b = rand(100);
using Distributions
indices = sample(1:1000, 100, replace=false) ## random indices for where the elements in a slice of the first dimension of A will match those in b.

## 2D example
A = rand(1000,100);
A[indices,1] = b; ## set 100 random rows of A will now have their first element match one element of b
Ared = A[findin(A[:,1], b),:]  ## find the rows in A where the first element is in B.  Return the full values of those rows.

## 3D example
A3 = rand(1000,10,100);
A3[indices,1,1] = b;
Ared3 = A3[findin(A[:,1,1], b),:,:];
julia> size(Ared3)
(100,10,100)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! 

You wrote, that "100 random rows of A will now have their first element match one element of b" are those not the same rows that matched before?

Comment: @Hainmueck That is just to create the situation where the match can occur in the first place.  In other words, since I don't actually have access to the matrix `A` and vector `b` that you are using, I needed to simulate a situation in which there would be a matrix `A` that has certain matches with a vector `b`.  Without this, if I just started with a random `A` and random `b` it is unlikely that many if any matches would exist (depending on how I did the random draws).

Comment: @Hainmueck In other words, those lines are just my work to produce a minimal reproducible example for you; something that you can work to incorporate in your own questions in the future.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details on that.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is fine and would work **if b was a vector**. The reason it doesn't is that you're probably trying to index using a 2-dimensional array (i.e. rank 2) which simply happens to only have one column, rather than a vector (i.e. rank 1) array. I.e. I'm sure if you do `size(b)` the result will be `(2,1)` rather than `(2,)` which is what it should have been.

If you obtain the corresponding vector for b, (e.g. `collect(b)` ) your indexing operation should work fine.

Example:

```
julia> A = rand(Int64[1,10],3,4,2)
3x4x2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 10  10   1  10
 10  10  10  10
  1  10  10   1

[:, :, 2] =
 1  10  10   1
 1  10   1   1
 1   1  10  10

julia> b = [1; 3]    # this will work. NOTE THE RESULTING TYPE!
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 3

julia> A[b,:,:]
2x4x2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 10  10   1  10
  1  10  10   1

[:, :, 2] =
 1  10  10   1
 1   1  10  10

julia> c = [1 3]'    # this will not. NOTE THE RESULTING TYPE
2x1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
 3

julia> A[c,:,:]
ERROR: MethodError: `index_shape_dim` has no method matching     index_shape_dim(::Array{Int64,3}, ::Int64, ::Array{Int64,2}, ::Colon, ::Colon)

julia> A[collect(c),:,:]    # this will work again, c is now a vector
2x4x2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 10  10   1  10
  1  10  10   1

[:, :, 2] =
 1  10  10   1
 1   1  10  10
```